# Can't run symfony project because of an error unserialize()

Tags: php, symfony

While I was working with my controllers my computer crashed and I needed to restart it. Then I decided to start my project with the `php bin/console server:run` command, but I got the following error:

[image: error]

I don't think it's from my project. For first time I see an error like this. It doesn't say from where it is. By the time my computer shut down I was working on an admin controller here it is but I don't think this is the problem. But here is the code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\TradeOffer;
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class AdminController extends AbstractController
{
/**
 * @Route("/BoardFind/Admin", name="AdminPanel")
 */
public function adminPanel()
{
    return $this->render('Home/Admin.html.twig');
}

/**
 * @Route("/BoardFind/Admin/AllUsers", name="AllUsers")
 */
public function adminPanelUsers()
{
    $Users = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();
    return $this->render('Home/ListUsers.html.twig', array(
        "arrayOfUsers" => $Users,
    ));
}

/**
 * @Route("/BoardFind/Admin/AllOffers", name="AllOffers")
 */
public function tadminPanelOffers()
{
    $Offers = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(TradeOffer::class)->findAll();
    return $this->render('Home/ListUsers.html.twig', array(
        "arrayOfOffers" => $Offers,
    ));
}

/**
 * @Route("/BoardFind/Admin/DeleteUser/{id}", name="DeleteUser")
 */
public function adminPanelUserDelete($id)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $entityManager->getRepository("App:User")
        ->find($id);
    $user->setIsDeleted(true);
    $entityManager->flush();
    return $this->redirectToRoute('AllUsers');
}

/**
 * @Route("/BoardFind/Admin/DeleteOffer/{id}", name="AllOffers")
 */
public function adminPanelOfferDelete($id)
{
    return $this->render('Home/Admin.html.twig');
}
}
```

In conclusion I would say that I really doesn't know what's happening and when I try to reconfigure my server it pops the following error:

[image: image 2]

Comment: Clear you cache

Comment: Try to clear your cache with `bin/console cache:clear`

Comment: Or failing that `rm var/cache`

Comment: Well I tryed the command and it didn't work

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try clearing your cache and if it doesn't work delete the folder sometimes the command doesn't work

Comment: ANd how does this differ from the comments already made an hour before? Or come to that, how does this differ from a simple comment!

Comment: well I tried with the commands and it didn't work but I deleted the file. I can upvote your comment if you want ?